# Where can I get pxelinux.0 for centOS 7?

Tags: centos, boot

I'm trying to do network booting via PXE. In particular I would like my client machines to install Cent OS7. However, my PXE boot server is running on Ubuntu 16.04.

Most of the tutorials explain how to install CentOS 7 via CentOS 7 PXE boot server.
Thus, they can easily do get pxelinux.0 by directly copying it **/usr/share/syslinux/* to for example */var/lib/tftpboot/*, while I cannot directly do it.

How can I get pxelinux.0 for CentOS7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pxelinux.0 is not specific to any particular Linux distribution. You can easily use Ubuntu’s version of it to boot CentOS, or vice versa. Only the kernel and initramfs/initrd files must really be specific to the OS version you're going to boot.

Comment: Thank you. Can I also use menu.c32 of ubuntu for centos?

Comment: Yes. Only the kernel and the initramfs/initrd files must really be specific to the OS version you’re going to boot.